# Blender 2.8 frame window scaling

Tags: modeling, animation, transforms

I have an animation (transform + rotation) that takes a 100 frames:

[image]

This is a trivial example, but in more animations, can I extend the frame window so that there is more time (e.g. from 100 frames to 200) to display detailed key shape animations. In this case moving either frame (at mark 0 and 100 offsets the other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the cursor to the timeline window and Press the **Home** key to show the whole range of frames.

Else click and drag on the bottom of the lighter gray bar at the bottom of the timeline to enlarge or shorten the amount of frames being displayed.

To extend the animation, select only the last keyframe and move it from frame 100 to whatever frame you want.

Comment: The whole range of frames is from 0 to 100 (in my case). I want to extend it so that the animation is "slower".

Comment: Select only the last keyframe and move it from frame 100 to whatever frame you want.